# Вызов хранимой процедуры при помощи hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

В базе данных есть хранимая процедура

> CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `totabank`()
>   select sum(summ) from summ_wallets

которая возвращает таблицей одну запись с суммой чисел. При помощи простой `jdbc` я могу сделать

> ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("call totalbank()");

и потом условно пробежаться по нему циклом и достать `int`-овое значение как `rs.getInt(1);`
Подскажите, как это можно было бы сделать при помощи `Hibernate`? Сёрфил интернет, рабочего примера так и не нашёл. Получалось как-то достать объект, кажется `Query`, но при вызове у него метода `toString()` он выдавал дефолтную `toString()`-строку объекта, а мне бы хотелось достать значение числом или строкой.

Answer (score 1):

```
// ранее получаем сессию хибернейта из фабрики сессий

org.hibernate.procedure.ProcedureCall call =
                    session.createStoredProcedureCall("totalbank");
            org.hibernate.procedure.ProcedureOutputs callOutputs = call.getOutputs();
            org.hibernate.result.Output output;
            while ((output = callOutputs.getCurrent()) != null) { // проверяем наличие выходных значений
                if (output.isResultSet()) { // если выходное значение результат запроса (некоторые процедуры могут возвращать количество обработанных строк, тогда вернет false)
                    List<Integer> result =
                            ((org.hibernate.result.ResultSetOutput) output)
                                    .getResultList();
                    // обработать результат
                }
                if (!callOutputs.goToNext()) // некоторые процедуры могут возвращать несколько последовательных результатов
                    break;
            }
```